Angular pass value to component (.html) from .ts using ngOnInit()
I have a project on Angular 18. I need to update the html page, regarding response value of ngOnInit(). When I test my code as below, I can see the test and maxPage values of ngOnInit() on html component as test = "ngOnInit" and maxPage = 2.
main.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrl: './main.component.css'
})

export class MainComponent {

  maxPage = 0;
  test!: string;

  constructor(){
    this.maxPage = 1;
    this.test = "constructor"
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.maxPage = 2;
    this.test = "ngOnInit"       
  }
}

main.html
<p>main works!</p>
<p> Max Page number : {{maxPage}}</p>
<p> Test : {{test}}</p>

However, if I change the logic with httpClient in ngOnInit() as follows, the values on html come from constructor as test = "constructor" and maxPage = 1, but still I need values from ngOnInit:
  ngOnInit() {
   
    this.subscription = this.dataTransferService.data$.subscribe(data => {      
      console.log(data);

      if (data !== null)
        {
          this.postMicroservice.getAllJonPosts().subscribe((data:any) =>{
            let result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).data);

            this.maxPage = result.maxPageNumber;
            this.test = "ngOnInit";        
          });    
        }
    });          
  }

I can validate my results in ngOnInit using console.log(). Could you please help me for showing the ngOnInit values on html. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

You might have an error in the browser console, you can check that.
For now, try parsing the response only if it's a string, then try to access the property.
Also you can use TypeScript safe access ?. to prevent "error accessing properties of undefined" issues.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.dataTransferService.data$.subscribe(data => {      
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
          this.postMicroservice.getAllJonPosts().subscribe((data:any) =>{
            let result = typeof data === 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
            const finalData = result?.data;
            this.maxPage = finalData?.maxPageNumber;
            this.test = "ngOnInit";        
          });    
        }
    });          
  }


Thanks for your answer. However, it didn't solve the problem. I have no error in the browser console. I assume that when my logic is inside the subscribe, the logic does work but can't update the .html file. I couldn't solve this problem.

@Johnny please replicate the issue on stackblitz here and share back on the question!

You are not getting updated values because those two lines in which you update values are unreachable. Do console log inside getAllJonPosts subscription to make sure this service is emitting data (most probably not)
Check my stackblitz demo here and it is working fine
    this.postMicroservice.getAllJonPosts().subscribe((data: any) => {
      // ***
      // try to Add Console.log() here. Your this service is not emitting data.
      // either there is no data or there is error
      // add error handling using ...getAllJonPosts().subscribe({next: fn(), error: fn(), complete: fn()})

      //let result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).data);
      let result = { maxPageNumber: 199999999 };
      this.maxPage = result.maxPageNumber;
      this.test = 'NG On Init Values';
    });


Thank you. I added console.log() and I can see that getAllJonPosts subscription emits data. I can print values to console, but I am unable to pass them to html.

In Angular you don't have to pass data to HTML, you just update the value, and the change detection cycle will automatically detect the change and update the UI. There is then the issue with the change detection cycle. What change detection strategy you have used in your component?
